# Wordpress - Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такой код, который из данных формы отправляет письмо, добавляет пользователя, пост от его имени и комментарий к посту:

```
<form class="single_contact_form flex_cc main_bg">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="contact_name" required>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="contact_phone" required pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" title="Международный, государственный или местный телефонный номер">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="contact_email" required>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
<?php if (isset($_GET['submitted'])) {

    $contact_name = $_GET['contact_name'];
    $contact_name = htmlspecialchars($contact_name);
    $contact_name = trim($contact_name);
    $contact_phone = $_GET['contact_phone'];
    $contact_phone = htmlspecialchars($contact_phone);
    $contact_phone = trim($contact_phone);
    $contact_email = $_GET['contact_email'];
    $contact_email = htmlspecialchars($contact_email);
    $contact_email = trim($contact_email);
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = trim($text);

    mail("[email]", "Новое сообщение", "Имя:".$contact_name."\nEmail: ".$contact_email."\nНомер телефона: ".$contact_phone."\nСообщение:".$text."");

    $user_id = get_user_by('email', $contact_email);
    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $contact_name, 'password', $contact_email );
    } else {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    }

    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'clients',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'author' => $user_id
        );                       

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    endwhile;

    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        $post_meta = array(
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $contact_name ),
            'post_content'  => 'Нет',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'clients'
            );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_meta, true ); 
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'object_types', 'Не добавлено', true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'area', 'Не добавлено', true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'adress', 'Не добавлено', true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'client_phone', $contact_phone, true);

    } 

    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $data = array(
        'comment_post_ID'      => $post_id,
        'comment_author'       => $user_info->display_name,
        'comment_content'      => $text,
        'comment_date'         => date('d-m-Y'),
        'comment_approved'     => 1,
        );

    wp_insert_comment( $data ); 
    die;
} ?>
```

Все отлично работает, меня устраивает, вроме одного НО: если передать два раза одно и то же Имя(contact_name), выдается такая ошибка

```
Recoverable fatal error: 
Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 781
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит по следующей причине. Привожу выдержку из документации по функции `wp_create_user()`:

> Возвращает ID, если удалось добавить пользователя. Если создать не удалось (имя или мыло уже существуют), вернет объект WP_Error со следующими сообщениями об ошибке...

В итоге, первый раз пользователь создался и по вернувшемуся `ID` Вы делаете свои дела и всё работает. А во второй раз `ID` не возвращается, а возвращается объект `WP_Error` и ваш код пытается обработать его как ожидаемую строку - вот и ошибка. Используйте функцию `is_wp_error()`, чтобы делать проверку и на основе неё решать, вызывать ли `WP_Query` или нет.

Comment: То есть уникальным должен быть не только email, но и имя? если я  правильно понимаю. Первый параметр в wp_create_user() - это логин?

Comment: Все правильно, только не имеет отношения к коду, приведенному в вопросе. В коде есть проверка на существование пользователя и второй раз wp_create_user не вызывается. А проблема в другом, и я описал это в своем ответе.

Comment: А вообще, конечно, я не понимаю, как можно работать с кодом и не знать, в какой строке твоего кода возникает ошибка. Включите отладчик, что ли.

Comment: О, да я не обратил внимания. ТС неправильно скопировал код проверки `if ( ! $user_id ) {` из моего ответа на свой предыдущий вопрос. Ну так мы точно никуда не приедем...

Answer (score 0):

Все из-за этой строчки:

```
post_status' => 'published',
```

Надо

```
post_status' => 'publish',
```

Вы неправильно указываете статус поста. Цикл while не находит таких постов. $post_id не присваивается значение.

Как следствие, не срабатывает как нужно `if (! $post_id)`, т.е. код внутри if работает всегда.

Всегда вызывается функция wp_insert_post, которая уже при втором вызове возвращает в $post_id объект WP_Error.

При попытке выполнить add_post_meta не удается $post_id преобразовать в строку. Код вылетает с сообщением об ошибке, приведенном в вопросе.

Comment: спасибо, учел ваше исправление, но причиной ошибки было не это)

Comment: Просветите тогда, что ли

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @campusboy. Действительно, я не учел, что имя - это логин, нужно делать его уникальным, а, собственно, имя, записывать в first_name. Итак, код:

```
$user_id = get_user_by('email', $contact_email);
    if ( ! $user_id ) {
// добавим генетарор случайной строки
        $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $string = '';
        $max = strlen($characters) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
        }
// сгенерируем логин из имени+случайных символов
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login' => ''.$contact_name.'_'.$string.'',
            'user_pass'  => 'password',
            'user_email' => $contact_email,
            'first_name' => $contact_name,
            );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
    } else {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    }
```